# React Native- error -> Route First should declare a screen while using stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-redux

React Native- 
Route 'First' should declare a screen, Not sure! Why this error is appearing ?

Please find the attached screenshot of the dir as well.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQOLl.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Register from './src/container/Register';
import MobileVerification from './src/container/Verification/MobileVerification';
import SignUpOtp from './src/container/SignUpOtp/SignUpOtp';




const Navigation = StackNavigator ({
  First: {
    Screen: Register
  },
  Second: {
    Screen: MobileVerification
  },
  Third: {
    Screen: SignUpOtp
  }
});

export default Navigation;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `screen` instead of `Screen`.

```
const Navigation = StackNavigator({
    First: {
        screen: Register
    },
    Second: {
        screen: MobileVerification
    },
    Third: {
        screen: SignUpOtp
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks man!!! It worked out.. Being new to this I wasn't able to detect where I was wrong.